# Fetching data using Python & lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, python-2.7

I have a my HTML which looks like below. I would like to get the text which is in the `<span class="zzAggregateRatingStat">`. According to the e.g given below I would get 3 and 5.

For this work I am using Python2.7 & lxml

```
<div class="pp-meta-review">
<span class="zrvwidget" style="">
    <span g:inline="true" g:type="NumUsersFoundThisHelpful" g:hideonnoratings="true" g:entity.annotation.groups="maps"    g:entity.annotation.id="http://maps.google.com/?q=Central+Kia+of+Irving++(972)+659-2204+loc:+1600+East+Airport+Freeway,+Irving,+TX+75062&gl=US&sll=32.83624,-96.92526" g:entity.annotation.author="AIe9_BH8MR-1JD_4BhwsKrGCazUyU5siqCtjchckDcg5BAl5rOLd9nvhJJDTrtjL-xFI8D42bD_7">
        <span class="zzNumUsersFoundThisHelpfulActive" zzlabel="helpful">
            <span>
                <span class="zzAggregateRatingStat">3</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                      out of
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                <span class="zzAggregateRatingStat">5</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    people found this review helpful.
            </span>
       </span>
   </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: *get the text which is in the .* <-- finish this sentence please

Comment: ... and finish the question by showing what you have tried.

Comment: Im really sorry for the typo. Stackoverflow took that as a HTML tag

Answer (score 4):

The following code works with your input:

```
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.parse('text.html').getroot()
for span in root.xpath('//span[@class="zzAggregateRatingStat"]'):
    print span.text
```

it prints:

```
3
5
```

I prefer using `lxml`'s *xpath* over *CSSSelectors* though they can both do the job.

ChrisP's example prints `3` but if you run it on your actual input we get errors:

```
$ python chrisp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chrisp.py", line 6, in <module>
    doc = fromstring(text)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2532, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:48270)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1545, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71812)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1424, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70673)
  File "parser.pxi", line 938, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:67442)
  File "parser.pxi", line 539, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63824)
  File "parser.pxi", line 625, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64745)
  File "parser.pxi", line 565, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64088)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: EntityRef: expecting ';', line 3, column 210
```

ChrisP's code can be changed to use `lxml.html.fromstring` - which is a more lenient parser - instead of `lxml.etree.fromstring`.

If this change is made it prints `3`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I am not entirely able to put down your code for the web site http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=7101561317478851901&view=feature&mcsrc=google_reviews&num=100&start=0&ved=0CFYQtQU&sa=X&ei=mwR0T_HtEILFkAXXt4GwCQ. It keeps on giving different errors

Comment: changing lxml.etree.fromstring to lxml.html.fromstring works! tanx!
only problem is that you don't have pretty_print option in lxml.html :(

Answer (score 0):

This is [clearly documented at the lxml website](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html)

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

sel = CSSSelector('.zzAggregateRatingStat')
text = '<span><span class="zzAggregateRatingStat">3</span></span>'
doc = fromstring(text)
el = sel(doc)[0]
print el.text
```

Comment: thank u for the answer, i've been trying this code on the web site http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=7101561317478851901&view=feature&mcsrc=google_reviews&num=100&start=0&ved=0CFYQtQU&sa=X&ei=mwR0T_HtEILFkAXXt4GwCQ but all in vain, can you please look into it

Comment: @Zulaikha, if you are trying to get ratings for businesses, you may want to look into the APIs available from Google and Yelp rather than scraping pages.