# Converting XML illegal &char to utf8 - python

Tags: python, html, xml, unicode

There is a list of XML and HTML character references at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.

However there are things that aren't defined at all in that list but they were used in older HTML scripts. When I am processing the `Senseval-2 format (with fixes)` dataset from http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/data.html, I encounter the following words where it breaks my script which tried to use `xml.et.elementTree` to parse the data.

**What are the unicode equivalence of these words?**

```
&and.
&and.A
&and.B
&and.D
&and.L's
&backquote.alim)
&backquote.ulema
&dash
&dash.
&dash."
&dashq.
&degree.
&degree.C
&ellip
&ellip.
&ellip.0
&ellip.1
&ellip.11
&ellip.2
&ellip.23
&ellip.28
&ellip.38
&ellip.4
&ellip.6
&ellip.64
&ellip.?"
&ellip.two
&times.
```

my script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
s1 = 'train-fix.xml' # from http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/Data/Sval1to2.fix.tar.gz
tree = et.parse(s1)
root = tree.getroot()
```

gives this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "senseval.py", line 4, in <module>
    tree = et.parse(s1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 41, column 113
```

Comment: Those aren't xml entities, the should terminate whit a `;`, not a `.`. Entity reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/

Comment: any idea what they are?

Comment: not really. `dash` could be a [html5 character entity](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), but `ellip` on the other hand isn't a valid entity anywhere I could find, neither is `degree`...

Comment: There is a list of entities in the DTD file linked from that page, but sans actual character definitions. As for the error, etree is right: without the trailing `;` this is just not XML.

Answer (score 4):

The "words" look like malformed [entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). A valid entity reference has a semicolon at the end. I looked at **test-fix.xml** (in Sval1to2.fix.tar.gz) and it seems very likely that `&dash` (or `&dash.`) is meant to represent some kind of dash or hyphen. The file has the `.xml` extension and it would be fairly close to being well-formed XML if the bad entity references were fixed.

On the page that you link to (http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/data.html), it says:

> Please note that our converted data will not "parse" as true xml text. This is due to the fact that in the original sense-tagged text, characters that require special handling in xml are not escaped, and so forth. We are considering ways to make this data "true" xml, and would be most grateful for any feedback on how to best do this.

So even though the document looks very much like XML, it is not XML and the people who published it are well aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer that made it possible to parse your xml using Python lxml package:

[Fetching data using Python & lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908503/fetching-data-using-python-lxml)

Install the lxml package from here: http://lxml.de/

And use this code:

```
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.parse('train-fix.xml').getroot()
```

Hope it'll work for you

Comment: +1 for the `lxml` parses but it doesn't resolve the problem of `what are those characters?` =(

Answer (score 3):

The basic but disappointing answer is: they're typos (using `.` instead of `;`).

Here's most of them:

- times → http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d7/index.htm
- degree → http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm
- dash → http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=dash&preview=entity
- ellip → http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm

… and so on, you have to look at the context for some of these, to judge whether the original text author meant something specific, or simply typo'ed even worse (dashq‽).

Your most appropriate course of action is to use a simple chain of string `replace` method calls to fix the mess, before parsing.

Answer (score 2):

if you have Linux available use xmllint to find errors and fix them

```
xmllint --recover ~/tmp/test-fix.xml --output ~/tmp/test-fix-fixed.xml 
/home/luis/tmp/test-fix.xml:179: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
inate, Hesse and the Saarland; North Rhine-Westphalia, Baden-Wu&umlaut.rttemberg
                                                                           ^
/home/luis/tmp/test-fix.xml:179: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
Bavaria would remain untouched, and the planned five East German La&umlaut.nder
...
/home/luis/tmp/test-fix.xml:3832: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
Charlie Watts today) we should be ready to hit the road together as Lyndon &and.
                                                                           ^
/home/luis/tmp/test-fix.xml:3841: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: corpus line 1 and lexelt
</lexelt>
     ^
/home/luis/tmp/test-fix.xml:3842: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<lexelt item="behaviour-n">


                                                                           ^
```